# Data is not showing up in a firebase database console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I am trying it with my android app. In my app, I am simply saving name on database which is very basic there is message showing Data saved successfully, but when I am trying to see it in firebase database console it is showing nothing even root url is not showing. I have also set Firebase rules to true for both read and write permissions.

Please look at my code below:

POJO Class:

```
package com.app.elaryx;

public class Data {

String name;

public Data(){

}

public Data(String name){

    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
}
```

JAVA Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
EditText name;
DatabaseReference dRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            button.setText("Saving...");

            if(name.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                button.setText("SUBMIT");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Data d = new Data();

                d.setName(name.getText().toString());

                dRef.push().setValue(d).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            button.setText("SUBMIT");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {

                            button.setText("SUBMIT");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

[My Firebase console Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRq8E.png)

In code everything seems fine to me .Please let me know the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have done a very silly mistake and hence you are not getting the result, since you've set the value in your model class but when the time of getting the value, you've not done anything.

for setting a value you're fine`d.setName(name.getText().toString())` but when you are passing the data this needs some value, and for this you've to provide the result by using **d.getName()**, the machine will not do that.

do like this in your code for setValue and I'm sure you'll get the result. It is sometime we neglect this type of mistakes, but these are really important to be seen otherwise you'll suffer.

```
dRef.push().setValue(d.getName()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        button.setText("SUBMIT");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        button.setText("SUBMIT");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Learn from your mistakes and become better everyday! Happy learning. Mark this answer right by hitting the right tick on this answer if you found this useful.

**EDITS**

Try this method and tell me that if it works or not!

First of all in your DatabaseReference do initialize like this

```
dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Names");
```

and then in your code do like this :

```
Data d = new Data();

            d.setName(name.getText().toString());

            dRef.setValue(d.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        button.setText("SUBMIT");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        button.setText("SUBMIT");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: yes, i know that but that is for showing data in app here my problem is i am unable to see my saved data in firebase console  it is showing nothing. i have provided my console picture link above.

Comment: yea dude, i have tried your solution also but it is doing the same thing as mine.After saving data it is not showing up in my firebase console in JSON format.

Comment: Then try like this and tell me if it works or not! See the . edits of my answer